# Cannot find name 'Promise'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactxp

I am having issue while running react-xp for web.i get this error message while running "Cannot find name 'Promise'".Thanks in advance
Please check github issue here 
[react-xp issue](https://github.com/dabit3/reactxp-starter/issues/1)

Comment: Did you install all the dependencies? Did you require `Promise` where you're using it?

Answer (score 2):

You should install required packages beforehand. Simply install following two packages first.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/es6-promise
npm install --save-dev @types/es6-collections
```

Then add corresponding type information to `react-native.d.ts` file as below.

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/es6-promise/index.d.ts" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed my problem very similar to this one

https://github.com/dabit3/create-xp-app/issues/2

inside your `tsconfig.json` file in the root folder, change:

```
..."compilerOptions": { "target": "es5", ...
```

change the `es5` -> `es6`